# Expressão lógica para (Enquanto ou Se) Criar repetição até que o usuário acerte a resposta

Tags: portugol, pseudocódigo

Estou tendo problemas em uma questão para definir o resultado de uma pergunta no VisualG, de maneira que se o usuário responde forma errada a pergunta irá se repetir até o usuário acerta.

A pergunta é: "se esta de acordo responda com (s) para sim ou com (n) para não".

Aqui está o código que criei:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var
  RESPOSTA: CARACTERE
inicio
        Enquanto RESPOSTA <> "n" faca
        Escreva("Esta de acordo?:")
        Leia(RESPOSTA)
          Se RESPOSTA <> "n" entao
            Escreval
            Escreval("Resposta incorreta.")
            Escreval("Vamos tentar novamente.")
            Escreval
            Escreval("Lembre-se!")
            Escreval("Para Responder SIM, Digite a LETRA (s), ou Digite a letra (n) para Responder Não.")
            Escreval("Boa Sorte!")
            Escreval
          Fimse
          Se RESPOSTA = "n" entao
            Escreval
            Escreva("Parabéns, voçê acertou!")
          Fimse
        Fimenquanto
fimalgoritmo
```

O problema é que eu só consegui colocar a letra `n` para funcionar como "Não".
Gostaria de saber se tem alguma formar de eu também conseguir colocar a letra `s` para a resposta "Sim".

Isso tudo de maneira que o a frase de resposta incorreta se repita até o usuário acerta a resposta de modo que fique `N` para não e `S` para sim.

Comment: Ola Kellvem, bom, não sei se você esta cursando algum curso que é necessario o uso do visualG, mas uma ferramenta muito boa para quem esta aprendendo a programar é o Portugol Studio, tem muito mais funcionalidade que o visualG, possibilita até a criação de partes gráficas na tela, da pra desenvolver seu primeiro joguinho e tudo mais!

bons estudos.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código otimizado ficará assim:

```
var
  RESPOSTA: CARACTERE
  CONDICAO: LOGICO
inicio
      CONDICAO <- VERDADEIRO


      ENQUANTO CONDICAO = VERDADEIRO FACA
           Escreval("==========================================")
           Escreval("               Lembre-se!                 ")
           Escreval("         Use LETRAS MAIUSCULAS            ")
           Escreval("  Para Responder SIM, Digite a LETRA (S)  ")
           Escreval("ou Digite a letra (N) para Responder Não. ")
           Escreval("               Boa Sorte!                 ")
           Escreval("==========================================")
           Escreval("    ")


      Escreval("Esta de acordo?: ")
        Leia(RESPOSTA)
        CONDICAO <- FALSO

      ESCOLHA RESPOSTA
         caso "s"
           Escreval("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
           escreval("Parabéns, você acertou!")
           Escreval("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

         caso "n"
           Escreval("***************************")
           Escreval("    Resposta incorreta.    ")
           Escreval("***************************")
           Escreval("                           ")
           Escreval("  Vamos tentar novamente.  ")
           Escreval("                           ")
           Escreval("                           ")
           Escreval("                           ")

           CONDICAO<- VERDADEIRO

        outrocaso
           Escreval("                           ")
           Escreval("                           ")
           Escreval("############################################")
           Escreval("    Você  digitou um caracter inválido     ")
           Escreval("############################################")
           Escreval("                           ")
           Escreval("                           ")
           CONDICAO<- VERDADEIRO

           fimescolha

      FIMENQUANTO

fimalgoritmo
```

Optei por usar o comando [ESCOLHA-CASO](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/estrutura-de-selecao-multipla-escolha-caso/) em vez do comando [SE-ENTAO](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/estrutura-de-decisao-se-entao-senao/), pois será mais complexo implementar seu pseudocódigo usando este comando(se-então).

Entretanto, vale mencionar que a otimização do pseudocódigo é realizada de inúmeras formas, pode ser que encontre, na internet ou com seu professor, a solução do seu problema com outros comandos, entretanto totalmente funcional.

O funcionamento do comando ESCOLHA-CASO esta descrito abaixo:

> As palavras reservadas desta instrução são `escolha`, `caso` e
>   `fimescolha`, sendo opcional o uso da `outrocaso`, como ocorre com a
>   instrução `se... entao` que pode usar o `senao` (seleção composta) ou
>   `não` (seleção simples).
>
> É importante destacar que esta instrução de seleção já possui a sua
>   operação relacional definida e não pode ser utilizada outra além da
>   igualdade, que é implícita nesta instrução (**nunca aparece o símbolo
>   = na instrução**). Por meio dela só é possível verificar se existe igualdade entre um valor inteiro ou caracter desejado que se queira
>   avaliar, onde sua veracidade resultará somente na execução das outras
>   instruções disponíveis no caso que corresponde ao valor igual ao
>   avaliado.
>
> Caso nenhum dos valores estejam especificados como um caso desta
>   instrução de múltipla escolha será executada as instruções disponíveis
>   no `outrocaso`, se o mesmo existir, ou o algoritmo continuará sua
>   execução após o `fimescolha`.
>
> Forma Geral de Sintaxe
>
> ```
> escolha (<identificador>)
>   caso <valor_1>
>     primeiro bloco de instrução
>   caso <valor_2>
>     segundo bloco de instrução
>   caso <valor_3>
>     terceiro bloco de instrução
>   outrocaso
>     bloco de instrução do outro caso (valor diferente de todos anteriores)
> fimescolha
> // continua as instruções do algoritmo em execução
> ```
>
> A grafia `<valor_1>`, `<valor_2>` e `<valor_3>` correspondem aos
>   possíveis valores inteiros ou caracter que serão comparados ao valor
>   que está armazenado no que será descrito no início
>   desta instrução, logo após a palavra reservada escolha, estando o
>   mesmo entre parênteses.
>
> Assim, será realizada a operação relacional de igualdade sem que
>   símbolo da mesma esteja descrito, explicitamente, na instrução
>
> **Fluxograma**:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Estruturas de Controle em pseudocódigo](https://cae.ucb.br/conteudo/programar/algoritmo/new_estruturadecontrolebcc.html)